# Access i-th element, which is inside the element of an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, json, list, arraylist

I have an element named SavedSearch, which contains several other elements, as shown in the screenshot. One of its elements, data, contains more elements, one of them is again by the same name data. Basically, data contain data which contains an ArrayList of size 8, from 0 to 7. I can access the elements of data, of 0-th postion by:
`savedSearch.getItemData().data.get(0);`
However, this 0-th position contains more elements, how do I access elements which is further inside savedSearch.getItemData().data.get(0);, that is, at 0th postion, there are several elements, how do I access them. Screenshots have been attached for your reference. Any help would be highly appreciated. In the first screenshot, I need to access the value of "fixed"(bottom of the image), which is inside i-th postion
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use :

```
savedSearch.getItemData().data.get(0)
    .data.get(item_you_want);
```

? You can also

```
[type] array=savedSearch.getItemData().data.get(0);
[typeItem] item=array.data.get(numerYouWant);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your outcome of arraylist looks like a SavedSearchExtra Object..

You can check like below and fetch the parameters at 0 index position.

```
SavedSearchExtra obj = (SavedSearchExtra) savedSearch.getItemData().data.get(0);
obj.getFixed();
obj.getBath();
```